# How to add image/video widget in GvrView of Google Cardboard?

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I am new to google cardboard and trying to implement a very simple demo.
I have tried with VrVideowidget & panowidget separately but failed to implement it with GvrView. My work with code and output is given below.

I have added a GvrView which provide split screen automatically, after that i want to add same image/video into each screen so that it can appear well on google cardboard . The view I am adding via addView() appear single instead of two on both screen. I have added it on onDrawEye(). Please help me to reslove.

My final aim is to create a very basic demo of image/video on  Google Cardboard with required feature.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends GvrActivity implements GvrView.StereoRenderer {


    GvrView gvrView;

    private ImageView imageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        imageView = new ImageView(this);

        gvrView = new GvrView(this);

        gvrView.setRenderer(this);

        setContentView(gvrView);

    }

 @Override
    public void onDrawEye(Eye eye) {

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
       // gvrView.addView(imageView);
        gvrView.addView(imageView,400,400);

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **VrPanoramaView** instead, code sample is as follow:

## add panowidget lib in your project

```
import com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView;

VrPanoramaView panoWidgetView = (VrPanoramaView) findViewById(R.id.pano_view);
panoWidgetView.loadImageFromBitmap(img,null);
panoWidgetView.resumeRendering();
```

Comment: ohk, right now I am working on some other project and will inform you once I implement it

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but my understanding is that you use onDrawEye to render images specific to the individual eyes, while you use onNewFrame() for non-eye specific rendering. 
So moving

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
       // gvrView.addView(imageView);
        gvrView.addView(imageView,400,400);
```

to onNewFrame() should be enough.

Comment: ohk, right now I am working on some other project and will inform you once I implement it.